# I want to build a grid app that renders items from a json file or a generated list with nuxtjs

Tags: json, nuxt.js

Build a grid app that renders items from a json file or a generated list. The items would be
filtered by shapes and colors. All items would be selected by default, and the grid title should
reflect the active filters.
**Filters:**
● All should be selected initially
● Multiple filters can be selected (differentiate the states)
● Deselecting the last filter should select all filters
**Grid title:**
Title should changed based on the active filters

1. When all the colors and shapes are selected: “All items:"
2. When all the colors and a multiple shapes or all the shapes and multiple colors are
   selected: "Multiple items:"
3. When all the shapes and a single color is selected: “All red items:"
4. When all the colors and single shape is selected: “All oval items:”
5. When multiple shapes and a single color is selected: “Multiple red items:"
6. When multiple colors and single shape is selected: “Multiple oval items:”
7. When a single color and single shape is selected: “Round oval items:"
   **Requirements:**
   ● Build in Nuxtjs
   ● Style with s(css)
   ● Make it responsive
   ● Have authentication (hardcode the credentials)
   ● Write tests

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What did you tried so far? Looks heavily like some homework that you expect the community to solve for you.